# Show that $A' \cup B' \cong A'' \cup B''$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that if $A' \cong A''$ and $B' \cong B''$, and further $A' \cap B' = \emptyset$ and $A'' \cap B'' = \emptyset$, then $A' \cup B'  \cong A'' \cup B''$

$\cong$ denotes bijection.

Suppose $|A'| = x.$ Then $|A''| = x$ by hypothesis. Similarly, $|B'| = |B''| = y.$ Since $A'$ and $B'$ are disjoint, $|A' \cup B'| = x + y.$ Similarly, $|A''\cup B''| = x + y.$ Thus the conclusion follows.

Does this argument make sense?

Comment: The argument makes sense when all the cardinalities are finite.

Comment: The argument makes sense (when all cardinalities are finite, as pointed out above) but besides the fact that the argument won't work in the infinite case--it also isn't fully rigorous.  To be fully rigorous you should probably work from the definition of a bijection, which is to say a function with certain properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:A'\to A''$ and $g:B'\to B''$ are bijections then under these conditions the function $h:A'\cup B'\to A''\cup B''$ prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$ if $x\in A'$ and $x\mapsto g(x)$ if $x\in B'$ is well defined and is also a bijection.